# WPF getting data entered by user in datagrid

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a data grid and a class with first name and last name and a button which creates a new row and allows you to input another name. My goal is to click another button and display them in alphabetical order but I am not too sure to get the data that the user filled in so I can arrange it

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

1. You can create a object from your List. And you can use events in change input elements. All changes in inputs will cause changes in records in List. This can allow you to save user changes.

//or

2. When you take action to store the input elements in the datagrid, you can loop through the input element type with reflection. You can continue the storage process by looking at the values of the input elements you found as a result of the comparison.